# Spring WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter keeps throwing IllegalStateException because of @Order

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have extended WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but every time I start Jetty, I get the exception:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. Order of 2147433647 was already used, so it cannot be used on com.xtl.mis.support.config.SecurityConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$11a4eacf@332c45ff too.

I previously had not annotated the class with @Order and started getting the exception.  Currently, I have my class annotated with @Order(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE - 50000).  I've tried several different values for this annotation, but always get the above exception saying the @Order must be unique and the one calculated was already used.  I'm using Spring Security 3.1.4.RELEASE and Spring Security JavaConfig 1.0.0.M1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I've fixed this.  I had a central @Configuration class called AppConfig which also had an @Import({SecurityConfig.class}) annotation on it.  I removed the @Import annotation and added @ComponentScan and now it works.

Comment: you should mark your own answer as excepted :D so that it isn't shown on the tab Unanswered http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered

Answer (score 0):

When extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in an integration test, you may as well replace..

```
@Import({SecurityConfig.class})
```

..by..

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
```