# @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am facing the problem with multiple entry points to my Spring app. I am pasting below my configuration.

```
@Configuration 
@EnableWebMvcSecurity 
public class EntryPointsConfiguration {

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.springapp.mvc"})
@Order(1)
public static class ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic()
                .and()
                .antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().hasAnyRole(Role.USER, Role.ADMIN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.springapp.mvc"})
@Order(2)
public static class FormLoginConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf()
                .disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/codebase/**", "/resources/**", "/about", "/signup", "/signup/check").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin*").hasAuthority(Role.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/home/**").hasAnyAuthority(Role.USER, Role.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/meetings*").hasAnyAuthority(Role.USER, Role.ADMIN)
                .antMatchers("/people*").hasAnyAuthority(Role.USER, Role.ADMIN)
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .formLogin()
                .usernameParameter("j_username")   // default is username
                .passwordParameter("j_password")   // default is password
                .loginPage("/auth/login")    // default is /login with an HTTP get
                .failureUrl("/auth/failure")   // default is /login?error
                .loginProcessingUrl("/auth/login/process")    // default is /login with an HTTP post
                .permitAll()
        .and()
                .logout()
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login")
                .logoutUrl("/auth/logout")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .eraseCredentials(false)
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider);
    }
}
```

}

web.xml

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Meeting Assistant</display-name>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.ico</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>userPanel.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.springapp.mvc.configuration</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Servlet mvc-dispatcher:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

<context:spring-configured />

<context:annotation-config />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

WebAppInitializer:

```
 public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

public SecurityWebApplicationInitializer() {}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{EntryPointsConfiguration.FormLoginConfigurationAdapter.class,
                          EntryPointsConfiguration.ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter.class,
                          WebSecurityConfig.class};
}

@Override
protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class<?>[]{ WebConfiguration.class, PersistenceConfiguration.class };
}

@Override
protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{ "/" };
}

@Override
protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
    CharacterEncodingFilter characterEncodingFilter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
    characterEncodingFilter.setEncoding("UTF-8");

    return new Filter[] { characterEncodingFilter };
}


}
```

WebSecurityConfig:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig extends SecurityConfig {

   public WebSecurityConfig() {
       super("MeetingAssistant-security");
   }


}
```

WebConfiguration:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 @EnableSpringConfigured
 @ComponentScan(basePackages= "com.springapp.mvc")
 public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver viewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource() {
    ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    messageSource.setBasename("messages");
    return messageSource;
}

@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
    localeChangeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
    registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor);
}

@Bean
public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
    CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
    cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(StringUtils.parseLocaleString("en"));
    return cookieLocaleResolver;
}

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/**");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/codebase/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/codebase/**");
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    StringHttpMessageConverter stringConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter();
    stringConverter.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);

    converters.add(new ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(stringConverter);
    converters.add(new ResourceHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new SourceHttpMessageConverter());
    converters.add(new AllEncompassingFormHttpMessageConverter());

    converters.add(new Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter());

    converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

}
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: @Order on WebSecurityConfigurers must be unique. 
Order of 2 was already used, so it cannot be used on 
com.springapp.mvc.configuration.EntryPointsConfiguration$FormLoginConfigurationAdapter$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$a72c8c8c@74647003 too.
```

I tried to change annotations according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20153523/spring-websecurityconfigureradapter-keeps-throwing-illegalstateexception-because) but unsuccessfully.

What am I doing wrong?

Btw, I would be very grateful if you could recommend good multiple Entry points tutorial in Spring with java based conf (REST, Form login, OAuth2).

cheers

**EDIT 1:**

Ok, so I updated the configuration as you asked for. Still getting the exception despite removing @EnableWebSecurity. Spring Security updated to 3.2.4.RELEASE.

**EDIT 2:**

I thought that providing the same package may cause the exception so I created 2 different packages and put 2 implementations of AuthenticationProvider.

Next, I changed the

`basePackages=com.springapp.mvc.configuration.rest` in the ApiWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter

and

`basePackages=com.springapp.mvc.configuration.form` in the FormLoginSecurityConfigurationAdapter.

This is what I got:

```
  Could not autowire method: public void org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.setObjectPostProcessor(org.springframework.security.config.annotation.ObjectPostProcessor)
```

I am using Transaction Management with ASPECTJ mode. Can this somehow mess around?

BTW. I am using Spring 4.0.0.RELEASE.

Comment: Do they even need to be ordered?

Comment: Try using just one of the annotations `EnableWebSecurity` and `EnableWebMvcSecurity`. I think `EnableWebMvcSecurity` includes the functionality `EnableWebSecurity` offers.

Comment: @AndreiStefan is correct that only EnableWebMvcSecurity is necessary, but that should not cause the error. What specific version of Spring Security are you using? Did you try updating to the latest version of Spring Security (3.2.4.RELEASE)? Can you provide how the configuration is getting initialized (i.e. web.xml or ApplicationInitilizers) for Spring MVC and the parent context? My guess is that you have specified the Spring Security to be loaded in both the parent and the child context.

Comment: Thanks for interesting. I updated almost the entire configuration. Exception still occurs.

Comment: Post the code for WebSecurityConfig class.

Comment: Done. You already have entire configuration. The persistence conf only is not revealed.

Comment: One more question - what is the package of `EntryPointsConfiguration`. If it is `com.springapp.mvc` that could be the reason why you are getting this error as the configuration is being detected during `component-scan`

Comment: The package of the class is com.springapp.mvc.configuration

Comment: I thought that autowiring the same instance of AuthenticationProvider could break this so I created another instance of AuthenticationProvider in different package and this led me to different exception - described in EDIT 2.

Comment: You can only have a single instance of AuthenticationProvider defined to use Autowired (unless you also use qualifiers). What does SecurityConfig look like?

Comment: I gave up attempting setting up configuration in one file at the moment due to time restrictions. I separated each configurer in its own file and this solution worked immediately. I will try to resolve former configuration in some time.